# Unable to connect source and target using jsplumb

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jsplumb

```
  Uncaught #<Object>
  a @ jsPlumb-all-min.js:3
  jsPlumbUtil.extend.setConnector @ jsPlumb-all-min.js:3
  jsPlumbUtil.extend.h @ jsPlumb-all-min.js:1
  jsPlumb.Connection @ jsPlumb-all-min.js:3
  window.jsPlumbInstance.R @ jsPlumb-all-min.js:1
  window.jsPlumbInstance.connect @ jsPlumb-all-min.js:2
```

this is the error code got in console

my function

```
    function initJsPlumb(divId)
{

    //$("#"+divId).append("<div style='position: absolute;width:59px;height:45px;' align='center' id='startImg'><img src='images/start_mc.png' /></div>");//No I18N
    $("#startImg").offset({ top: $("#"+divId).offset().top+10, left: $("#"+divId).offset().left+25});


    jsWrklwInstance = jsPlumb.getInstance({
        /*ConnectionOverlays : [
            [ "Arrow", { location:1 } ,arrowCommon],//No I18N
        ],*/
        Container:divId
    });


    var fillColor = "gray";//No I18N
    jsWrklwInstance.Defaults.Connector = [ "Flowchart", { stub:10, gap:[5,-10]}];//No I18N
    jsWrklwInstance.Defaults.DragOptions = { cursor: "pointer", zIndex:2000 };//No I18N
    jsWrklwInstance.Defaults.PaintStyle = { strokeStyle:"gray", lineWidth:1.2 };//No I18N
    jsWrklwInstance.Defaults.Endpoint = [ "Dot", { radius:0.1 } ];//No I18N
    jsWrklwInstance.Defaults.MaxConnections = -1;//No I18N

    //jsWrklwInstance.Defaults.EndpointStyle = { radius:4, fillStyle:"gray" };
    jsWrklwInstance.Defaults.Anchors =  [ "BottomCenter", "TopCenter" ];//No I18N

    //$("#"+divId).append("<div style='position: absolute;width:25px;height:25px;border:1px solid #fff;background-color:#00ff00;opacity:0.2' align='center' id='success_startDummy_DestImg' class='startDummy'></div>");//No I18N
    $("#success_startDummy_DestImg").offset({ top: $("#"+divId).offset().top+140, left: $("#"+divId).offset().left+49});//No I18N

        var overlays = [
            [ "Arrow", { location:1 }, arrowCommon ]//No I18N
        ];

    jsWrklwInstance.connect({source:'startImg', target:'success_startDummy_DestImg', overlays:overlays,maxConnections:2});//No I18N

jsWrklwInstance.Defaults.Connector = [ "Flowchart", { stub:10, gap:[5,10]}];//No I18N
}
```

error occurred at the line in my function -  `jsWrklwInstance.connect(`

Comment: While trying to connect source and target div this error occur. I don't know what i am missing here. please help me out in this

Comment: can you create a fiddle ?